# Source of Crassus quote on greed?

Tags: ethics, quote

> "Greed is but a word the jealous inflict upon the ambitious"

This quote is often attributed to Marcus Licinius Crassus. Unfortunately, I'm struggling to find much on Google beyond various "inspirational quotes" sites repeating the same basic info: the quote, and the speaker.

I'd like to confirm that this was, in fact, a quote from Crassus and take a look at the original statement in the original Latin context if I can. Does anyone know of the source for this quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure it wasn't Crassus.  A [google n-gram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=greed+is+a+word%2C+jealous+inflict%2C+jealous+men+inflict%2C+upon+the+ambitious&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cupon%20the%20ambitious%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bupon%20the%20ambitious%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bupon%20the%20Ambitious%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cupon%20the%20ambitious%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bupon%20the%20ambitious%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bupon%20the%20Ambitious%3B%2Cc0) for parts of the quote turns up nothing.  There were some results for "upon the ambitious" but none for the other parts of the quote.  This means that the quote does not appear in Google's large compendium of scanned books.

Also a [google scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22&q=%22jealous+men+inflict%22&btnG=) turns up one result:  from a document about STARZ Spartacus.  STARZ Spartacus is apparently a TV series, and the quote also appears on the STARZ Spartacus twitter.  Therefore, it seems the most likely explanation is that this quote was said by the character of Crassus on the STARZ Spartacus TV show.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the quote is from the TV show Spartacus, from the fourth season 'Spartacus: War of the Damned', episode 6, [Spoils of war](https://subslikescript.com/series/Spartacus-1442449/season-3/episode-6-Spoils_of_War)